# Get ID from product before and after

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to get IDs from products before and after the product I am currently looking and so I can get the info from those products and make a next product and previous product buttons

I am working on Opencart version 2.3.0.2

This is all in product.php controller all of this is around line 277, after the data['product_id'] I added my code

```
        $data['product_id'] = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($data['product_id']);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($result['product_id'] < $data['product_id']){
                $data['product_before_id'] = $result['product_id'];
            } else {
                $data['product_before_id'] = 0;
            }

            if ($result['product_id'] > $data['product_id']){
                $data['product_after_id'] = $result['product_id'];
            } else {
                $data['product_after_id'] = 0;
            }

        }
```

I was trying to get it but got illegal string offset

**The altered answer**

```
        $next_product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id + 1);
        while($next_product === false){
            $product_id = $product_id + 1;
            $next_product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
        }

        $previous_product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id - 1);
        while($previous_product === false){
            $product_id = $product_id - 1;
            $previous_product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
        }


        if ($previous_product !== false) {
            if ($previous_product['product_id'] == $data['product_id']) {
                $data['product_before_id'] = 0;
            } else {
                $data['product_before_id'] = $previous_product['product_id'];
            }
        } else {
            $data['product_before_id'] = 0;
        }

        if ($next_product !== false) {
            if ($next_product['product_id'] == $data['product_id']) {
                $data['product_after_id'] = 0;
            } else {
                $data['product_after_id'] = $next_product['product_id'];
            }
        } else {
            $data['product_after_id'] = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Increment or decrement the current ID by 1 and use a get query to check if the id exists keep decrementing or incrementing until you find a valid id. You can post the model query for better understanding of your query

Comment: Please provide more information like what file you're working in. Based on the little information you have provided my guess is that `$data['product_id']` doesn't exist when you pass it to your model function or `$result['product_id']` doesn't exist. Illegal string offset occurs when an associative array in PHP does not have an element with the designated string key

Comment: I edited it with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote is flawed to begin with. The `getProduct` function retrieves the information about a single product, not all products.

Based on what you would like to do I would simply get the current page's product ID and then check the ID's on either side of it. So if the product ID is 4 check if both product ID 3 and 5 exist.

This can be achieved by simply running the `getProduct` function for both of them because if the product ID argument does not exist in the database the function will just return false.

Example:

```
$product_id = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];

$previous_product_id = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id - 1);
$next_product_id = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id + 1);

if ($previous_product_id !== false) {
    $data['product_before_id'] = $previous_product_id;
} else {
    $data['product_before_id'] = 0;
}

if ($next_product_id !== false) {
    $data['product_after_id'] = $next_product_id;
} else {
    $data['product_after_id'] = 0;
}
```

Make sure that you use the `!==` operator and not the `!=` operator as `!==` checks that the type is actually a boolean and therefore a value of false indicating that a product does not exist for the supplied product ID.

This answer applies only to retrieving the previous and next product. To retrieve a full set of all products ordered by their ID's would require a completely different answer.

Comment: Altered it a bit incase there is a empty space between so I get the next real product ID its edited into my question

Answer (score 0):

To get the Previous ID:

Create a new function in your Model that fetches Previous ID and Next ID using the current ID:

```
function  nextId($currentId) {
   //Replace MyTable with the name of your table
   $q= "SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE id >= $currentId ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
}

function  prevId($currentId) {
   //Replace MyTable with the name of your table
   $q= "SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE id <= $currentId ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

}
```

Above is the query that would be used . 
Now run the query using your preferred database library and return your result.

That should do it